# Console Log not working properly - Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript

i'been trying to get the console log of a sample code.

It's working fine on Google appscript editor (Showing each log when it's supposed to), but i can't get to work on visual studio code.

I attach here a picture of the situation, it only logs the console.log outside of the function, but i need to see the result of each comparison inside the function.

What should i do to solve this?

```
    function manos() {
    let manoIzq = ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5"];
    let manoDer = ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5"];
  
    for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < manoIzq.length, j < manoDer.length; i++, j++) {
      let dedoIzq = manoIzq[i];
      console.log(dedoIzq);
      let dedoDer = manoDer[j];
      console.log(dedoDer);
  
      if (dedoIzq === dedoDer) {
        console.log("true");
      } else {
        console.log("false");
      }
    }
  }
  

  console.log("false");
```

[VISUAL STUDIO CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOqX6.png)

Comment: Is your function actually called in any way? Like `manos();`?

Comment: Depending on the use case, you can also use a debugger in VSCode to see how your code runs. This is recommended over using Console Log statements. And as @SergeySosunov said, make sure your function is called. 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Comment: No, i didn't know i had to call the function because i didnt have to on the appscript editor (where i first started coding). Thank you both, i added  return manos(); on the end of the code and now i can see each log on the console.